# Calculate number of months between 2 dates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to calculate number of full months between 2 dates

```
declare @startdate date='2021-03-03';
declare @enddate date='2021-05-02';

select datediff(mm,@startdate,@enddate)
```

This is giving me output as 2 but I want it to be 1 as it should count full months only. So from 03/03/2021 to 03/04/2021 is 1 month and from 03/04/21 to 02/05/21 is still not full month. So, the answer  should be 1 in this example. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The concept of a "full month" is subject to interpretation, is it not? Does a "full month" exist between Jan 31 and Feb 28? How about Feb 28 and Mar 28? Does a leap year affect that decision?

Comment: Two though is technically the correct answer since what is "a month" - if you asked how many days are between the dates then there are 60 days, which is two 30-day months and 2.14 Februarys, months don't run consecutively from arbitrary dates, they are strictly quantized.

Comment: I agree that 2 is the correct answer here. The first "full" month is 2021-03-03 to 2021-04-02 inclusive, and then the *next* month starts on 2021-04-03 and ends on 2021-05-02, inclusive. If you were dealing with date *and* times my answer would be different (then 2021-03-03T00:00:00 to 2021-04-03T00:00:00 would be a "full" month), but you aren't here. It's more like 2021-03-03 to 2021-05-02T23:59:59.999~.

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
declare @startdate date='2021-03-03';
declare @enddate date='2021-05-02';

select datediff(mm,@startdate,@enddate) - case when dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,@startdate,@enddate), @startdate) > @enddate then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Full month is a tricky thing in some cases.

1. If I start on Jan 31 and end on Feb 28 is that a full month?
2. If I start on Feb 28, 2019 and end on Feb 28, 2020 is that 12 full months?
3. If I start on Feb 29, 2020 and end on Feb 28, 2021 is that 12 full months?

If you did not care about these cases and just wanted a simplistic rule like "it's a full month if the EndDay>=StartDay you could adjust the difference with a "*Case When Day(Enddate)<Day(Startdate) Then 1 Else 0 End*"